# Indent as much as the width of a word

Tags: spacing, indentation

Here is my basic problem:

I want to write on a line

```
Thesis: "something really long that
         should continue here like this"
```

How can I do that? (without tabular)

Edit:

I am using this inside a tabular environment like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}  
other lines & text here \\
&Thesis: "something really long that\\
&should continue here like this"\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The following questions might be of help: [Change hanging indent in description list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7008/2693), [Paragraph indented to absolute horizontal position](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13856/2693).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\phantom{Thesis:}`. This will leave as much space as would be taken up by `Thesis:`

Here are two methods for your specific case:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|l}
other lines & text here \\
&Thesis: "something really long that\\
&\phantom{Thesis: }should continue here like this"\\
\end{tabular}

\hrule
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
other lines & text here \\
&Thesis: "something really long that\\
&\noindent\phantom{Thesis: }should continue here like this"\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. This works fine in the general case. Unfortunately something gets messed up in my use, I should have been more clear on the description. I'm using this inside a tabular, and if I use the phantom command, it just skips a line. I edited the question.

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example (including `\documentclass`) that illustrates the problem. Difficult to provide guidance otherwise.

Comment: You are right, I included a complete example now.

Comment: Have updated the solution to reflect the MWE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hanging` package for this sort of thing:

Here I've created a command which takes one argument, and creates a hanging paragraph with the indent equal to the width of the argument. (I've changed your column width to show the wrapping.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\hangwidth}
\newcommand{\myhang}[1]{\settowidth{\hangwidth}{#1}\hangpara{\hangwidth}{1}#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{3cm}}
other lines & text here \\
&\myhang{Thesis: }``something really long that
should continue here like this''\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]